# Can someone explain a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

Ok, so here is what I do know about forEach.

a forEach loop pulls from the array and the function placed inside gets called on every element inside the array.  I just can't seem to grasp the concept.  I'm still learning JS and it's been a month so please be patient with me. I've tried using a for loop and it seems to work, I just dont know how to incorporate it as a forEach

```
function CreateSuspectObjects (name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    color: name.split('')[1],
    speak() {
      console.log(`My name is ${name}`);
    }
  };
};

let suspects = ['Miss Scarlet', 'Colonel Mustard', 'Mr. White'];

let suspectsList = [];

// Using a for loop

for(let i = 0; i < suspects.length; i++){
    suspectsList.push(CreateSuspectsObjects(suspects[i]))
};
```

Like i've said I'm still learning JS and dont really understand a forEach loop.  I've tried suspects.forEach(CreateSuspectObjects), but it is just not making any sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

A `forEach` loop is just a way to simplify a traditional `for` loop. You pass it a function, which is just whatever normally goes inside the `{}` of a for loop. However, with the function, you need to be aware of the parameter order:

```
item
index
array
```

This means that if you want the index of your item, not the item itself, you need to use the second parameter of the function:

```
arr.forEach((item, index) => doSomething.with(index));
```

Note that the above is called an *arrow function*, and it's a new ES6 feature. It's the equivalent of:

```
arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
  doSomething.with(index);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Transitioning your current code to work equivalently using [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop requires a minimal change:

```js
function CreateSuspectObjects (name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    color: name.split(' ')[1],
    speak() {
      console.log(`My name is ${name}`);
    }
  };
}

let suspects = ['Miss Scarlet', 'Colonel Mustard', 'Mr. White'];

let suspectsList = [];

// Using forEach()
suspects.forEach((name, i, suspects) => {
  // use name instead of suspects[i]
  suspectsList.push(CreateSuspectObjects(name))
});

console.log(suspectsList);
```

However, as you are creating a new array by transforming each object in an existing array, you should use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead:

```js
function CreateSuspectObjects (name) {
  return {
    name, // short-hand for name: name
    color: name.split(' ')[1],
    speak() {
      console.log(`My name is ${name}`);
    }
  };
}

const suspects = ['Miss Scarlet', 'Colonel Mustard', 'Mr. White'];

// Using map()
const suspectsList = suspects.map(name => {
  return CreateSuspectObjects(name);
});

console.log(suspectsList);
```

You can condense this even more since `name => { return CreateSuspectObjects(name); }` does *exactly* the same thing as `CreateSuspectObjects`, by changing the statement to

```
const suspectsList = suspects.map(CreateSuspectObjects);
```

---

#### `array.forEach()` vs. `array.map()`

The reason that `suspects.forEach(CreateSuspectObjects);` did not work is due to the difference between `forEach()` and `map()`. `forEach()` loops over each value in `suspects` and executes the function provided for its *side-effect*. In my first snippet, the side-effect is `suspectsList.push()`, which adds a value to the existing array `suspectsList`.

However, `CreateSuspectObjects()` does not have any side-effects; it simply returns an object, which `forEach()` will ignore, since the return value of the function is not used.

The reason that `suspects.map(CreateSuspectObjects);` did work is because `map()` creates an array the same size as `suspects`, and loops over each value in `suspects` to execute the function provided for its *return value*. `map()` uses the return value of the function as the initializer for each respective value in the array that it created, then returns it.

Answer (score 1):

forEach is pretty simple. It is a property of any array, and calling it results in the function provided as a parameter being called for each item in the array. So for what you're after:

```
function CreateSuspectObjects (name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    color: name.split('')[1],
    speak() {
      console.log(`My name is ${name}`);
    }
  };
};

let suspects = ['Miss Scarlet', 'Colonel Mustard', 'Mr. White'];

let suspectsList = [];

suspects.forEach(s => {
    suspectsList.push(CreateSuspectsObjects(s))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach to replace the for loop by using it like this.

It will iterate through the `suspects` array and refer to each of its object inside the array sequentially just like i++ does. Here I  refer to each of them as `suspect` to make it easy to understand then you push it into the array just like what you do with `suspects[i]`.

About the arrow operator, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) if you don't know how it works.

```js
function CreateSuspectObjects (name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    color: name.split('')[1],
    speak() {
      console.log(`My name is ${name}`);
    }
  };
};

let suspects = ['Miss Scarlet', 'Colonel Mustard', 'Mr. White'];

let suspectsList = [];

suspects.forEach(suspect => suspectsList.push(CreateSuspectObjects(suspect)))
console.log(suspectsList)
```

Comment: ok i see what happened and my misunderstanding....I had to google the arrow operator, but what i was doing that kept giving me an error was passing 'suspects' back into the CreateSuspectObjects.